# Migration windows server 2003 to 2012 R2 fundation error

Tags: windows, migration

I followed the steps of Microsoft from here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/04/01/step-by-step-active-directory-migration-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2012-r2 /

I have done all the steps except disable the catalog and demote the old server 2003.

Server name 2012: server2 ip: 192.168.0.200

Primary dns: 192.168.0.200

secondary dns: 192.168.0.100

Server name 2003: server1 ip: 192.168.0.100

Primary dns: 192.168.0.100

secondary dns: 192.168.0.200

DNS users: 192.168.0.200

Result of the role transference (netdom query fsmo):
RID master server2.social.local
PDC server2.social.local
infrastructure master server2.social.local
schema master server2.social.local
domain naming master server2.social.local

I have left 10 hours and I have turned off the server1 2003 thinking that everything has been synchronized, this is when the problems have come to me. If I turn off server1 server2 does not work. I can log in with the users but the server is inaccessible to connect a network drive, instead if I can ping 192.168.0.200 and the name server2. Also now I miss a message that I have 9 days to activate the license because I'm not connected to a domain controller. When in users and computers of active directory -> domain controllers if I can see my two domain controllers, in DC type it appears that both are GC.

In the server2 2012 event viewer I have these errors->
ID 13566 ntfrs file replication service
The File Replication Service is examining the data in the system volume. The SERVER2 machine can not be converted to a domain controller until this process is complete. The volume of the system will then be shared as SYSVOL.
To check the SYSVOL share, at the command prompt, type:
net share
When the File Replication Service completes the exam process, the SYSVOL share appears.
Initializing the system volume may take a while. The time depends on the amount of data in the system volume.

ID 13566 ntfrs file replication service
The File Replication Service has problems enabling the replication of SERVIDOR1.social.local to SERVER2 for c: \ windows \ sysvol \ domain using the DNS name SERVIDOR1.social.local. FRS will keep trying.
 Here are some of the reasons why this warning may appear.

[1] FRS can not correctly resolve the DNS name SERVER1.social.local from this computer.
 [2] FRS is not running on SERVER1.social.local.
 [3] The topological information of this replica in Active Directory Domain Services has not yet been replicated to all domain controllers.

This event log message will appear once for each connection. Once the problem has been resolved, you will see another event log message indicating that the connection has been established.

In the 2003 server viewer I have these errors->
ID 13568 ntfrs file replication service
Type of event: Error
Origin of the event: NtFrs
Event category: None
Event ID: 13568
Date: 05/18/2018
Time: 16:39:46
User: Not available
Team: SERVER1
Description:
The File Replication Service detected that the replica set "DOMAIN SYSTEM VOLUME (SYSVOL SHARE)" is in JRNL_WRAP_ERROR.

The name of the replica set is: "DOMAIN SYSTEM VOLUME (SYSVOL SHARE)"
 The path of the replication root is: "c: \ windows \ sysvol \ domain"
 The volume of the replication root is: "\. \ C:"
 A replica set incurs the JRNL_WRAP_ERROR error when it can not find the record it is trying to read from the NTFS USN journal. This can happen due to one of the following reasons.

[1] The volume "\. \ C:" has been formatted.
 [2] The NTFS USN journal on the volume "\. \ C:" has been deleted.
 [3] The NTFS USN diary has been truncated in the volume "\. \ C:". Chkdsk can truncate the journal if it finds incorrect entries at the end of the file.
 [4] The File Replication Service was not executed on this computer for a long period of time.
 [5] The File Replication Service could not maintain synchronization with the disk I / O activity speed in "\. \ C:".
 Setting the "Enable Journal Wrap Automatic Restore" registry parameter to 1 will result in the following steps of automatic error recovery.
 [1] This team will be removed from the replica set during the first poll that will take place in 5 minute (s). If you do not want to wait 5 minute (s), run "net stop ntfrs" followed by "net start ntfrs" to restart the File Replication Service.
 [2] This equipment will be added back to the replica set during the poll that follows the deletion. Re-adding will trigger the complete tree synchronization of the replica set.

I'm going crazy to disconnect the server1 without releasing and leaving only the server2 running. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried a couple of times to go from server 2003 to 2012 r2 (Keep in mind this was years ago).

Doing a FMSO role transfer from 2003 to 2008 has its little bugs, i found that DFS never worked properly again, the way permissions were handled in IIS seemed to need some tweaking.

What i have done that is much easier and smoother.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/547c94ba-3826-4e7a-b9ad-80b308beced4/migrate-ad-users-from-2003-to-2008?forum=winserverMigration

Only difference use Sever 2008 r2 the trial will work fine

Dont forget about the other roles and features that are important to get working on the new server.

Then you can stand up a Server 2012 R2 server, and do the FMSO role transfer.

I know it doesn't answer your question directly, however TL;DR usually means it will not worth your time if there is a different path.

Comment: Before installing a 2008 I prefer to create another domain and copy the users with User Profile Wizard 3.12

Comment: You could do that, but I wouldn't, keep the same domain name, unless you 100% sure nothing in environment is dependent on that name, also keeping the same domain name when the FSMO roles transfer over everything will match and password will not need to be reset and etc. Also, unless this is not mission critical don't try to think to far out of the box, I am not saying Profile Wizard 3.12 will not work however a lot of people have done this same things many times and there is best practices.